# Accessing an HTML page saved locally on computer in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I have the following path of HTML page saved in local directory: "C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\b.html". Now I want to search for a word in this page:

```
url = r"C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\b.html"
page = open(url)
```

I want to write it as:

```
k="C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\b.html"
url = r k
page = open(url)
```

It is giving me error, how to apply read mode `r` in this case because if I write `url=r"k"` the `k` won't be taken as a variable but a string.

I am getting this error:

> IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: 'C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\x08.html'

Answer (score 0):

The raw string prefix only applies to literals. The string is already irreparably damaged, since it is impossible to unilaterally determine without inspection whether the original was supposed to be `r'\b'` or `r'\x08'`. All you can do is perform a replace operation and hope you pick the right one.

```
k = k.replace('\x08', r'\x08')
```

Comment: text_files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.html')]
print text_files   , this gives me a list of html files ['a.html', 'b.html', 'c.html', 'd.html', 'e.html', 'f.html', 'g.html'] now I want to open each of these files stored locally and find whether a word is present there or not ? I have done this for a paricular file when I give it's whole path , now the problem is if I have stored them in list then how to iterate ?

Comment: url="C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\b.html"
url = url.replace(url,r')   how to replace "C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\b.html" with r"C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\b.html"   when I have stored "C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\b.html" in variable url